# Help with "Net stat"

Tags: command-prompt, command-line-arguments

I used the net user command on a friends computer and now I can't access it. Can anyone tell me what the password would be from this line?

net user Username *".password1

thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251394

Seems like maybe the command is:
net user Username *
and the password which was entered when prompted (because of the asterisk) is:
".password1

But I'm not quite sure I fully understand the question. If I'm incorrect, perhaps you should add some background information to your question.